# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError.Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I try to using gem 'devise'. And I would want that the user created a post.

posts_controller

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  end
```

but browser show an error

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

I need to create a Users controller and write it strong parameters or what?

how fix?

sorry for my bad English

**UPD**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify which attributes you allow to pass to the model.

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  # ...
end

def post_params
  # Require params[:post] and allow its title and text key
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text) 
end
```

Comment: thank you, but it already have in my controller.I updated question

Comment: @vveare138 You don't seem to be using the `post_params` however. You need to pass that into the `build` method.

Comment: oh, sorry.I have not seen it